C# long compilation errors when using generics
When using generic types in C# and fully qualified namespaces, the compiler will give very long compilation errors like

cannot implicitly convert type Task<Result<System.Generic.Collection.List<MyCompany.MyProject.MyModule.MySubModule.MyClass>>> to Task<Result<System.Generic.Collection.List<MyCompany.MyProject.MyModule.MySubModule.MyOtherClass>>>

I would find this much more readable instead

cannot implicitly convert type Task<Result<List< MyClass>>> to Task<Result<List< MyOtherClass>>>

Or even

cannot implicitly convert type (...)MyClass to (...)MyOtherClass

Is there a way to tell compiler or IDE to keep things short ? I use Visual Studio and Rider as an IDE.

You would really not like C++

No, because it's important to be able to diagnose and fix issues with wrong or unexpected namespaces. In fact, the full type description also includes the assembly name, which is missing, and which would help diagnose issues of duplicated types in different assemblies (which are treated as different types for the purposes of casting).
